# python dict for multiple repeated keys file handle

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python. I have below testfile. Same keys are repeated in testfile.

Below is the testfile output:

```
Police Station1
kill: 10
dead: 20
Encounter: 5

Police Station2
kill: 15
dead: 20
Encounter: 6

Police Station3
kill: 20
dead: 15
Encounter: 10
```

How to get kill and dead details using python dict. I used below code. It is printing only police station 3 details and not policice station 1 and 2.

Below is the code:

```
d = {}
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if ":" not in line:
                continue
        key, value = line.strip().split(":", 1)
        d[key] = value

for k, v in d.iteritems():
    if k == 'dead':
        v = v.strip()
        print v
    if k == 'kill':
        v = v.strip()
        print v
```

I am getting below output:

```
15
20
```

I am expecting:

```
Police Station1
kill: 10
dead: 20

Police Station2
kill: 15
dead: 20

Police Station3
kill: 20
dead: 15
```

How to handle this kind of output and get the above output.

Note: I am not stick to dict any other methods or solution would be fine as long as it produce desired expected results

Comment: Could you post your desired results?

Comment: In your dictionary, using keys for all police stations you are overwriting the values. May be you need an list as the value where you can append the dead count etc

Comment: added expecting results

Comment: dictionaries are maps from a *unique* keys to values. If you want to hold "multiple values", use a *container* as a value and store them there.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
holder = ""
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
      line = line.strip()
      if line != "":
        if ":" not in line:
          d[line] = {}
          holder = line
        else:
          key, value = line.strip().split(":")
          d[holder][key] = value
        #here in the below line, you were overwriting the values each time
        #so only the values that were assigned last time will remain
        #In your case, {'kill': ' 20', 'Encounter': ' 10', 'dead': ' 15'}

        #d[key] = value

for k in d:
  print k
  for item in d[k]:
    if item != "Encounter":
      print item+" : "+d[k][item]
```

**output:**

Police Station1

kill :  10

dead :  20

Police Station3

kill :  20

dead :  15

Police Station2

kill :  15

dead :  20

Comment: this will give me the sum of all dead and kill for all police stations, I think we need to push these values to dict then print

Comment: So, there was an edit in the question after my answer, I've edited my code to suit the question now

Comment: I am glad that it was helpful, just accept the answer if it works for you

Comment: Do not do `for k in d.keys():`, this is an anti-pattern, in Python 2, it makes a *new list of the keys*. That is wasteful and unnecessary, just *iterate over the dictionary directly to iterate over the keys*: `for k in d:`. In Python 3, `d.key()s` returns a view, so this problem doesn't apply, but it is still redundant.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for the tip, edited my answer after it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
f = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()

f = [i.split() for i in f]
f = [i for i in f if len(i) > 0]


results = {''.join(f[i:i+4][0]):{f[i:i+4][b][0]:f[i:i+4][b][1] for b in range(1, 3)} for i in range(0, len(f), 4)}
print results

#gives you: {'PoliceStation1': {'dead:': '20', 'kill:': '10'}, 'PoliceStation2': {'dead:': '20', 'kill:': '15'}, 'PoliceStation3': {'dead:': '15', 'kill:': '20'}}
```

Comment: This is a really inefficient way to handle the file, reading the entire thing into memory and doing multiple intermediate data-structure transformations... you can build the map directly as you iterate line-by-line.

Comment: @Ajax1234, my values are increasing and random output in that case your suggestion code will not work and Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: How and where exactly are your values increasing?

Comment: In file output, now dead kill and encounter keys are exist but it fileoutput may vary some times it will increase keys kill, dead, encounter, injured etc

Comment: I don't see how your edit changes anything. Your main issue is on this line: `open('file.txt').read().splitlines()` which reads the entire file into memory, *and then splits on lines*. You don't want to do that, you want to iterate over the file lazily. Also, you should be using a with-block. Even **if** you wanted to do that, you should do something like `data = list(open('file.txt'))` anyway, without the redundant calls to `read` and `splitlines`... a file already iterates over the lines! The other issue is that you create intermediate lists using comprehensions for each step in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to nest your containers one level deeper. Here's your code again with a few tweaks:

```
dsub = d = {}
with open('testfile.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip() # strip whitespace fore & aft
        if not line:  # ignore blank lines
            continue
        if ":" in line:
            key, value = line.split(":", 1)
            dsub[key] = value
        else:   # lines without colons are no long ignored: they're the outer-level keys
            dsub = d[line] = {} # create a new sub-dictionary 

for station, dsub in d.iteritems():
    print station, dsub['kill'], dsub['dead']
```

If you want a *specific* entry from a dictionary you don't have to iterate over the whole thing in the hope of finding it—you can look it up directly, as in the example `dsub['dead']` above.

Note that in dictionary iteration the items come out in arbitrary order.  If that's a problem, you can either use `sorted(d.iteritems())` or you could say `from collections import OrderedDict` and work with that instead of ordinary `dict`s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support, I used your code it is printing everything. I want to print only kill and dead values

Comment: I'm pretty sure, judging by the code you've already written, that you could figure out how to make the change in the way things print. However, see edit.